# Sequence restrictions of SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table I have a column of type `nVarchar` or `nText`

Suppose value of a this col is like this `'... xxx yyy zzz ...'`

I use `SELECT` to search table with this column

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name like '%xxx yyy%'
```

Since the I can't force users to enter words with my sequence I want to give same result with this query too:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name like '%yyy xxx%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tokenize the user input into separate words inside your application code (not in sql) and then construct queries like

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE 
(col_name like '%yyy%') AND (col_name like '%xxx%') AND ...
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you might want to consider normalizing your table. Specifically, if "yyy xxx" is the same as "xxx yyy", you're storing an array (or list or whatever you want to call it) in one column, which breaks first normal form. Normalize it so that each of those atoms (i.e. "xxx", "yyy") are stored separately and are related back to your original record. Then it's almost trivial to do the kind of thing you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use both criteria, and "OR".

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE (col_name like '%xxx yyy%')
   OR (col_name like '%yyy xxx%');
```